# Boolean Algebra Unsure how to simplifiy an expression

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I'm having a lot of trouble with two problems the first is:

```
1) (y*w) + y + w
```

What I tried here is applying the distributive law as follows

```
(y*w) + (y+w)
((y+w) + y) * ((y+w) + w)
((y*w) + y) * ((y*w) + w)
```

then applying the absorption law and getting y*w but the answer is y + w, so I'm unsure how to get it using the laws of Boolean algebra.

2) The second problem I am having issues with is

```
Prove that if x*y = x then ~x*~y = ~y
```

What I tried was negating both sides of the first expression and plugging into the second but that isn't allowed in Boolean algebra it seems.

Comment: What does `*` represent here? Is that logical AND? This is a code-related site, so unless you have a concrete representation of this in some kind of programming language it's probably off-topic and better suited to the [CS site](https://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's also important to ask one question and one question only. Chaining things on the end with an "oh, also" complicates things. The one question, one answer format keeps things simple and focused.

Answer (score 0):

First question:

```
(x*y) + x + y
```

Just simplifies to:

```
x + y
```

Non-rigorous reasoning: `x*y` is only `TRUE` when `x` and `y` are both `TRUE`, but when `x` and `y` are both `TRUE`, `x+y` is already `TRUE` anyway, making the `x*y` part of the expression superfluous.

Rigorous reasoning: Create a truth table and realize that the output `(x*y)+x+y` is identical to `x+y`.

```
| Inputs |   Output  |
|--------|-----------|
| x |  y | (x*y)+x+y |
|--------|-----------|
| 0 |  0 |     0     |
| 0 |  1 |     1     |
| 1 |  0 |     1     |
| 1 |  1 |     1     |
|--------|-----------|
```

---

Second question:

```
Prove that if x*y = x then ~x*~y = ~y

x*y = x
y = 1        (divide both sides by x)

~x*~y = ~y
~x*~1 = ~1   (substitute in 1 for y)
~x*0 = 0     (substitute in 0 for ~1)
0 = 0        (anything*0 = 0)

Both sides of the expression are equal. Proof is complete.
```

Comment: Instead of  `y=1` maybe `y=1 V x=0`?